# How would I implement a simple text based menu in a console application?

Tags: c#

I would like to have the option in the Discount price calculator that I wrote for fun to start the program over and was wondering how I'd optimally go about doing it. I would like it to say something similar to: "Would you like to enter another price?" and if the user says "yes" or "y" or "no" etc, either restart the program or exit.I should probably use an if loop right? Can someone please show me how to implement it? Or point me in the right direction? I also feel like I should re-write the program to have methods but I'm unfamiliar with C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Figure_the_Discount
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string price, discount;
        decimal discountedPrice, savedAmount;

        //Receiving the price as input
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of the item.");
        price = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal numPrice = decimal.Parse(price);

        //Receiving the discount as input
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the discount that you wish to apply");
        discount = Console.ReadLine();
        //Receiving discount from input, divide by 100 to convert to percentile
        decimal numDiscount = decimal.Parse(discount) / 100;

        //Calculate the discounted price with price - (price * discount)
        discountedPrice = numPrice - (numPrice * numDiscount);
        //Calculate the amount of money they saved
        savedAmount = numPrice - discountedPrice;
        Console.WriteLine("The discounted price of this item is: ${0}\nYou saved: ${1}", discountedPrice, savedAmount);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me. There really isn't enough code to need to use methods, unless you want to add something else?

Comment: You should try to do what you said.

Comment: Looks like other people's answers will solve your issue.  Just thought I would let you know that you should use decimal.TryParse instead of decimal.Parse.  This way your program won't blow up on you if an invalid decimal is entered.

Answer (score 0):

The following loop will cycle through as long as the user specifies `y` or `yes` (not case sensitive) at the end of the program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string price, discount;
    decimal discountedPrice, savedAmount;
    bool startAgain = true;
    string line;

    // Loop again every time the startAgain flag is true.
    while (startAgain)
    {
        //Receiving the price as input
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of the item.");
        price = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal numPrice = decimal.Parse(price);

        //Receiving the discount as input
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the discount that you wish to apply");
        discount = Console.ReadLine();
        //Receiving discount from input, divide by 100 to convert to percentile
        decimal numDiscount = decimal.Parse(discount) / 100;

        //Calculate the discounted price with price - (price * discount)
        discountedPrice = numPrice - (numPrice * numDiscount);
        //Calculate the amount of money they saved
        savedAmount = numPrice - discountedPrice;
        Console.WriteLine("The discounted price of this item is: ${0}\nYou saved: ${1}", discountedPrice, savedAmount);
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Ask if the user wants to submit another price.
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another price?");
        // Record the spaceless, lower-case answer.
        line = Console.ReadLine().ToLowerCase().Trim();
        // Set the startAgain flag to true only if the line was "y" or "yes".
        startAgain = line == "y" || line == "yes";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string resp = "";
    string price, discount;
    decimal discountedPrice, savedAmount;
    do {
        .... // your previous code here
        ....
        Console.WriteLine("The discounted price of this item is: ${0}\nYou saved: ${1}", discountedPrice, savedAmount);
        Console.WriteLine("Another item?");
        string resp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    }
    while (resp == "y" || resp == "yes");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just s rough sample

```
string input = null;
do {


    //your code 

    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to insert another price?");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    if(input.ToLower() != "y" ||  //if responce to the question is not 'y' or 'yes', break the loop
         input.ToLower() != "yes")
    break;

}while(true);
```

**EDIT**

This program inserts a price till a user confirms that he wants to insert a new price, otherwise just exit.