# Option yes/no C# Console

Tags: c#

I'm creating a C# program for the Currency Converter by console. 
At the end I would to insert "Continue? (yes/no)". Here the user have to chose. I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
float Dollaro = 1.32f, Euro;
float Cambio;
string EuroStr;


        Console.Write("Euro: ");
        EuroStr = Console.ReadLine();
        Euro = float.Parse(EuroStr);

        Cambio = Dollaro * Euro;

        Console.WriteLine("Dollaro: " + Cambio);
        Console.WriteLine("Vuoi continuare? (yes/no)");
        Console.ReadLine();
        string risposta = Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            if (risposta.Equals("Y"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes");
                break;
            }
            else if (risposta.Equals("N"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No");
                break;
            }

        } while (risposta == "N");
```

Comment: your while loops needs to be round your entire console application

Comment: Related: [How would I implement a simple text based menu in a console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8902179)

Comment: now i don't get what's wrong with your code except the do while

Comment: Just saying, but the user _should press Shift_ if you compare the input to capital _N_. Or the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

you want something like that

```
float Dollaro = 1.32f, Euro;
float Cambio;
string EuroStr;

     do
     {
        Console.Write("Euro: ");
        EuroStr = Console.ReadLine();
        Euro = float.Parse(EuroStr);

        Cambio = Dollaro * Euro;

        Console.WriteLine("Dollaro: " + Cambio);
        Console.WriteLine("Vuoi continuare? (yes/no)");
        Console.ReadLine();
        string risposta = Console.ReadLine();

            if (risposta.Equals("Y"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes");
                break;
            }
            else if (risposta.Equals("N"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No");
                break;
            }

      } while (risposta == "N");
```

but that's just a sample, you need to give more information so i'll give you better example. what does your code supposed to do? what other option does the user have? and so on

Answer (score 4):

```
        float Dollaro = 1.32f, Euro, Cambio;
        string EuroStr;
        ConsoleKeyInfo risposta;
        do
        {
            Console.Write ( "Euro: " );
            EuroStr = Console.ReadLine ();
            bool result = Single.TryParse ( EuroStr, out Euro );
            if ( result )
            {
                Cambio = Dollaro * Euro;
                Console.WriteLine ( "Dollaro: " + Cambio );
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Please enter a number" );
            }
            bool check = false;
            do {
                Console.Write ( "\nVuoi continuare? (yes/no) " );
                risposta = Console.ReadKey ( true );
                check = !( ( risposta.Key == ConsoleKey.Y ) || ( risposta.Key == ConsoleKey.N ) );
            } while ( check );
            switch ( risposta.Key )
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Y: Console.WriteLine ( "Yes" ); break;
                case ConsoleKey.N: Console.WriteLine ( "No" ); break;
            } 
        } while ( risposta.Key != ConsoleKey.N );
```

I've changed some things:

- if I enter a *character* for the Euro - `FormatException` <sup>[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx)</sup>. So I've added a `TryParse()`;
- I've changed the response from `string` to `ConsoleKeyInfo` <sup>[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key.aspx)</sup> - this makes the check for "Y" or "N" easier and I think clearer, and there is **no** need to cast the user input with ToLower() <sup>[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower.aspx)</sup> and compare it with  a string;
- also a check if the user presses "Y" or "N", while the input is different, the same message will appear - `Console.Write ( "\nVuoi continuare? (yes/no) " );`

In general you should filter all data\info ( whatever ) comes from the user, to avoid exception.

Answer (score 2):

You should move code where you do operation to *do while loop*.

Try this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float Dollaro = 1.32f, Euro;
        float Cambio;
        string EuroStr;

        string risposta = "Y";

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Euro: ");
            EuroStr = Console.ReadLine();
            Euro = float.Parse(EuroStr);

            Cambio = Dollaro * Euro;

            Console.WriteLine("Dollaro: " + Cambio);
            Console.WriteLine("Vuoi continuare? (yes/no)");               
            risposta = Console.ReadLine();

            if (risposta.Equals("Y"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes");                    
            }
            else if (risposta.Equals("N"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No");                    
            }

        } while (risposta == "Y");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should fix your problem:
And you should make your variable "risposta" ToLower so that it doesnt matter if you type a small or big letter (y or Y)

```
float Dollaro = 1.32f, Euro;
            float Cambio;
            string EuroStr;

            string risposta = "Y";

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Euro: ");
                EuroStr = Console.ReadLine();
                Euro = float.Parse(EuroStr);

                Cambio = Dollaro * Euro;

                Console.WriteLine("Dollaro: " + Cambio);
                Console.WriteLine("Vuoi continuare? (yes/no)");
                risposta = Console.ReadLine();

                if (risposta.Equals("Y"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
                }
                else if (risposta.Equals("N"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No");
                }

            } while (risposta.ToLower() == "y");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'read' answer to be able to test it.

```
answer = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Tushar, Tell me how this is critique? The topic starter asked about reading input from the commandline and shows a `while` loop that does not uses 'readline', and i show him he needs to use a readline. (By now the topic starter showed more code but the readline is still outside the DO loop). Geez

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, you can also add "else" statements for other key presses.

```
    string key = "";
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Username: ");
        username = Console.ReadLine();          
        Console.Write("Is this correct? (Y/N): ");
        key = Console.ReadLine();
        if (key.Equals("Y") | key.Equals("y"))
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int num1, num2; 
char oPt;
string Count;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 1st Value");
    num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 2nd Value : ");
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(" + - * / ");
    oPt = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    if (oPt == '-')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (num1 - num2));
    }
    else if (oPt == '+')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (num1 + num2));
    }
    else if (oPt == '*')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (num1 * num2));
    }
    else if (oPt == '/')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (num1 / num2));
    }
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to calculate another? Yes (y) or No (n): ");
        Count = Console.ReadLine();
        var CountLower = Count?.ToLower();
        if ((CountLower == "y") || (CountLower == "n"))
            break;
        } while (true );
    } while (Count != "n");
}
```